# Android not able to set color for text view

Tags: java, android, textview

I am not able to set color to the text view.Contents will be similar to below

[image: Mobile content example]

Value of st comes from data base .The values can be between 0 to 1.
When User login into the app and then he will be shown customer an high level  related status and then when he further clicks a more detailed status of the task is shown.

As requested I have provided the completed code.

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Report:");
    listDataHeader.add("User Details");
    listDataHeader.add("Property Details");
    listDataHeader.add("Owner's Details");
    listDataHeader.add("Tenant's Details");
    listDataHeader.add("Appointment's Details");
    listDataHeader.add("Status's Details:");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> report = new ArrayList<String>();
    report.add(rkey1);

    List<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
    user.add(name1);
    user.add(mail1);
    user.add(contact1);

    List<String> property = new ArrayList<String>();
    property.add(padd1);

    List<String> owner = new ArrayList<String>();
    owner.add(oname1);
    if (!ocontact.equals("") || !ocontact.equals("")) {
        owner.add(ocontact1);
    }
    owner.add(oadd1);
    owner.add(omail1);

    List<String> tenant = new ArrayList<String>();
    tenant.add(tname1);
    tenant.add(tcontact1);
    tenant.add(tadd1);
    tenant.add(tmail1);

    List<String> appointment = new ArrayList<String>();
    appointment.add(appadd1);
    appointment.add(sdatenew);
    appointment.add(stimenew);

    List<String> status = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
      status.add(status_names1[i]);
      TextView txtListChild = (TextView) 
      ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
      txtListChild.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

   }

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), report); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), user);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), property);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), owner);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), tenant);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), appointment);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), status);

}
```

Comment: Why are using equals for int comparison? Give complete code. The error is because if condition is failing

Answer (score 0):

Try to define in the onCreate() the TextView instead:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity(){

    TextView txtListChild;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       txtListChild = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

     }

   private void prepareListData() {

     for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        status.add(status_names1[i]);
        txtListChild.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

     }

   }
}
```

Another thing you may try is to define the color in R and then:

```
txtListChild.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOURGREENCOLOR));
```